# Foundation Framework not working with VueJS for tab panel/content switching

Tags: javascript, vue.js, zurb-foundation, vuejs2

I have a login/signup wrapped in a `VueJS` component and am using `FoundationCSS/JS` for the tab panels and `VueJS` to get the values from the input. The error happens when I try to click on the other tab (i.e. when I click on signup tab, it doesn't display the signup panel). When I don't make the login/signup div a `VueJS` component, then the tab panel switching works fine but I wouldn't be able to get the values from the input. Any ideas on why this is happening and how to fix it?

Here's my form (one panel for login and another panel for signup):

```
<div id="authenticator-form">
    <ul class="tabs" data-tabs id="example-tabs">
        <li class="tabs-title is-active"><a href="#panel1" aria-selected="true">Login</a></li>
        <li class="tabs-title"><a href="#panel2">Sign Up</a></li>
    </ul>
    <div class="tabs-content" data-tabs-content="example-tabs">
        <div class="tabs-panel is-active" id="panel1">
          <input v-model="loginEmail" type="text" placeholder="email">
          <input v-model="loginPassword" type="password" placeholder="password">
          <button v-on:click="login" class="button primary" id="login">Login</button>

      </div>
      <div class="tabs-panel" id="panel2">
            <input v-model="name" type="text" placeholder="Name">
            <input v-model="signUpEmail" type="text" placeholder="Email">
            <input v-model="signUpPassword" type="password" placeholder="Password">
            <button v-on:click="signup" class="button primary" id="signup">Signup</button>
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here's the VueJS component:

```
let authenticator = new Vue({
  el: '#authenticator-form',
  data: {
    loginEmail: '',
    loginPassword: '',
    signUpEmail: '',
    signUpPassword: '',
    name: '',
  },
  methods: {
    login: function () {
        console.log("LOGGING IN WITH " + this.email)
    },
    signup: function() {
        console.log("SIGNING UP WITH " + this.email)
    }
  }
})
```

Comment: It would be better if you used a router-view , display your login page and signup page as different routes. I have made a jsFiddle( https://jsfiddle.net/wgqjouft/ ) of this. Have a look

Comment: And I think the class name is not tabs-panel, it is tabpanel , see docs ( http://foundation.zurb.com/sites/docs/v/5.5.3/components/tabs.html#tabs-deeplink-1 )

Comment: thanks that worked!